# review link on category page in magento

Tags: php, magento

I am using a template that displays reviews in the product page. In the category page however, the link to reviews from helper/summary_short.phtml goes the the /reviews/ link for the product.
It doesnt appear as if the template maker used a separate module for displaying the reviews on the product page.  So I need a way to change the reviews link on the category list products.

the summary_short page uses the following for the link

```
  <a href="#" onclick="var t = opener ? opener.window : window; t.location.href='<?php echo $this->getReviewsUrl() ?>'; return false;"><?php echo $this->__('%d Review(s)', $this->getReviewsCount()) ?></a>
```

i tried using a strait link to the variable `$this->getProductUrl()`, which returns a null value.
is there a way in the reviews to access the product url so that the review link from the category page goes to the product page and not the reviews page.

Comment: question is not clear. In which page you need product url ?

Comment: question edited. i want the reviews link from the category page to link to the product page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `<?php echo $this->getReviewsUrl() ?>`
with `<?php echo $this->getProduct()->getUrl(); ?>` to get product page url

Comment: thank you! so is this true for any attached content for a product?

Comment: Do you mean any product attribute?